# Fuzzy search for Japanese phone number

Tags: algorithm, search, fuzzy-search

Background: I want to create a Japanese phone number search with a fuzzy search. The Japan phone number has an area code which means the first 3/4 digits represent a region, for example:

a. 0773 = Amata District, Kyoto

b. 075 = Kyoto, Kyoto
[image]
Ref: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialing_codes_in_Japan

I intend to divide the phone number entered by the user into two parts: the first 3/4 digits (aka "area code") and "numbers after." Then, filter the data in the database, and extract the data which are the same area code. After that, fuzzy search the phone number in the extracted data and then output the result list.

What the algorithm or rule is the best for phone number data fuzzy searching? The rule of phone number data fuzzy searching should include insertion, deletion, and substitution data or not? Or just output the result, which must match the previous input text?

Comment: what do you mean by fuzzy search phone numbers? you don't want to find phone numbers that exactly matches the input number?

Comment: @A-_-S Japan phone number length is 10 - 11. If the user input does not complete data (e.g. 7 - 9 number), I want to show a result that is similar to the user input. As I know this behavior is named fuzzy search.

Comment: if I have an area code that is xyz can I have an area code with 4 digits that starts with xyzw? 
if so, do you want the algorithm return you both all the numbers that matches xyz-waaaa and xyzw-aaa for example?

Comment: @A-_-S I think I will align the area code as 3 digits (the above picture shows). And I want the algorithm return all the numbers which match the template input by the user: xyz-xxxxxxxxx. For example, user input 011-21345 --> output 011-21345xx

Comment: so why not sort all the numbers, and get all the numbers that starts with the user input prefix?